# Adding 2 to a variable each time

Tags: php

I need the variable $Dno to add two each time it prints in the loop.

Below is my code.

```
$Dno = '18' + '2';



        while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   

            //Description Binder from this Table in DB
            while($ffdata=$qqq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                    $dta =  $ffdata['code'];
                    $sq = "SELECT * FROM hcpc WHERE code = :dta";
                    $qr=$con->prepare($sq);
                    $qr->bindvalue(":dta", $dta);
                    $qr->execute();
                    while($hcdata=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $worksheet
                            ->setCellValue('C' . $Dno++, $hcdata['description']);
                    }
            }   

        }
```

As you can see, its now making 18 = 20.. but in the loop it will only add 1 each time.. So the next line would be 21.. I need it to be 22.

If I just did this code...'

```
$Dno = '18' + '2';



        while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   

            //Description Binder from hcpc Table in DB
            while($ffdata=$qqq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                    $dta =  $ffdata['code'];
                    $sq = "SELECT * FROM code WHERE code = :dta";
                    $qr=$con->prepare($sq);
                    $qr->bindvalue(":dta", $dta);
                    $qr->execute();
                    while($hcdata=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $worksheet
                            ->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']);
                    }
            }

        }
```

it also makes the first line  = 20 but then every line will also = 20

Comment: Please clarify: you want to increase your variable by 2 using increment operators, or override increment operator so it will increase your variable by 2 each time it's used?

Comment: expected result??? 20 or 36?

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<10; $i+=2) echo $i . ' > '; //0 > 2 > 4 > 6 > 8 >`

Answer (score 3):

You'd use `$this += 2` to increment by two. `++` will only increment by one. That's how the operator is defined.

In a more general sense, `$this += x` would increment by `x`, so you can define the increment to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can add 2 to a variable by, well, adding 2 to it:

```
$this = $this + 2;
```

or:

```
$this += 2;
```

> I still want it to end with ++

Seems arbitrary, but ok:

```
$this++;
$this++;
```

---

**Edit:** In response to the updated code in your answer, the concept is still the same.  Here you're incrementing the value by one when using it:

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $Dno++, $hcdata['description']);
```

Instead, add two to the value and use it:

```
$Dno += 2;
$worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']);
```

Or, as pointed out by @Steve in a comment below, since the original uses a *post*-increment, you'd change the value after:

```
$worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']);
$Dno += 2;
```

Comment: I did that and it is nto working... I did $this = '18' + '2'; then $this++ the first output is 20... the second output is 21... So no voting my question down and giving me that answer was wrong. The second output should be 22, then 24, and so on...

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: So you start with 20, and the output is 20.  Then you add one to it, and the output is 21.  How is this behavior unexpected?  Do you understand how addition works?

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 `" I did $this = '18' + '2'; then $this++"` Why are you doing `$this++` at all? As mentioned in every answer, instead of `$this++` uses `$this+=2`

Comment: wow.. If you took a second to read before mouthing off you would understand.. I get that ++ increments by only 1 so that was the part I was not getting. doingif $this = 18 and I did $this = $this + 2 that would only make the variable 20... one time. I am using a loop so I need it constantly increase by two.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: Then increase by two in a loop.  Instead of "mouthing off" maybe you can actually explain the problem?  (Note: Your question makes *no* mention of any loop.  So why are you surprised that no answer does either?)  If you want to add 2 to a variable, then add 2 to that variable.  This... really isn't difficult.

Comment: Now it is changed. Maybe it makes more sense now.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: I've updated the answer to reflect your new code.  The concept is really still the same, regardless of how else you use the variable.  All you have to do is add `2` to it.

Comment: So I would do $Dno = '18'; and $Dno += '2'; If so, That is incorrect, When I do that it prints all the inof on line 20.. It should be going up by 2 each time it prints.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: First of all, why are you using strings instead of numbers?  Second of all, in what way is this not working as expected?  Can you show your fully updated code?  Adding 2 to a value does increment it by 2.  I suspect the problem is elsewhere in your code.  `18` + `2` is `20`, so it sounds like the addition is working as expected.  So where else is it failing?

Comment: @David A note about your revised answer. `$var++` increments `$var` by one, but returns the original value. So to do the same but increment by 2, you would need to perform the increment **after** the method call: `$worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']); $Dno+=2;`

Comment: Im not sure hwo to paste my code in a comment without it looking horrid. What I posted above is the updated.. The only thing I changed, I took away the ++ and I added $Dno += '2'; after $Dno = '18'; So yes, The new value of $Dno is 20.. Problem though. It will forever be 20 because we are NOT telling it to increment inside of the loop like the ++ did.. We are telling it that its new value is 20 and thats all. I need to be able to say that same code you posted but inside the while loop for it to work. These variable can only be defined outside of the while to work though. That is the problem.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: So... Put the `+= 2` line *inside the loop*?  You're currently incrementing the value in the loop.  So why wouldn't you continue to increment the value in the loop?

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 You need to perform the increment `$Dno+=2` inside the while loop, directly after the call to `$worksheet->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']);`. Also, to format code within comments on stack overflow, surround the code with backticks (\`)

Comment: @Steve if I peform that after I get this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$Dno'`

Comment: @Kmiles1990123: A syntax error is another problem entirely.  Can you include in your question the code which produces that syntax error?

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 Thats just a syntax error, probably you just missed a semicolon. The entire code for the inner most loop should be: `while($hcdata=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $worksheet
                            ->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']); $Dno+=2;
                    }`

Comment: this is what it looks like `while($hcdata=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
       $worksheet
        ->setCellValue('C' . $Dno, $hcdata['description']); $Dno += '2';
      }`

Comment: Leave the quotes out @kmiles1990123

Comment: I was meesing up doing $Dno = '2'; when it should have been $Dno = 2; Thank you again so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$this += 2;
```

or:

```
$this = $this+2;
```

BTW, you firstly assigned the `'18'` (the string), you should have used integer `18`, of course PHP understood that and will cast type to integer, but better practice is to use proper type right off the beginning to avoid extra overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple custom function, for inline view:

```
<?php
    function incByTwo( &$inp ) {
        $inp += 2;
        return $inp; // So you could use this inline
    }

    // Test function:
    $test_var = 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
        print '<br />This is a test: '. incByTwo($test_var);

?>
```

**Update**

Now you could use something like this:

```
while($hcdata=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $worksheet
       ->setCellValue('C' . incByTwo($Dno), $hcdata['description']);
...
```

please test it before using, I haven't yet.

Comment: I dont see what value this brings `echo $this +=2;` both increments and outputs the variable

Comment: @steve I thought this might be better for readability, also thanks for your input. To be most honest, I've never tried.

Comment: Fair enough, also, judging by the OPs comments, showing the function's use in loop is probably helpful information

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain the `++` operator:

```
php > $x = 7;
php > $x++++;
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC) in php shell code on line 1
php > ($x++)++;
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC) in php shell code on line 1
```

That you leaves with the choices everyone else has shown:

```
$x += 2;
$x = $x + 2;
```